# Rendering rails model associations in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables below:

```
blogs (id, name, description)

user_blogs (id, user_id, blog_id)

users (id, email, gender)
```

I am looping through the users and I want to display all the user_blogs they belong to.  What would be the best practice to do this in a view?  I already have the code below working.  Now, I want to add a column that would display the blogs.name list based on the user_blogs association.

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.id %></td>
      <td><%= user.custom_id %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: do you already have associations setup in your models? If so could you share them?

Comment: User
  has_many :user_blogs

User_Blogs
 belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :blog

Blogs:
  has_many :user_blogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following would work:

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.custom_id %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <% user.user_blogs.blog.each do |blog| %>
          <li><%= blog.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <$ end %>
```

However (assuming you have your associations set up correctly), if you put in your User class the following:

```
has_many :user_blogs
has_many :blogs, through: :user_blogs
```

you can get rid of the user_blogs, and use the following in your view.

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.custom_id %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <% user.blogs.each do |blog| %>
          <li><%= blog.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <$ end %>
```

Comment: Just noticed something in his example code. Not quite sure `patient` is being used in his block?

Comment: probably one of those find/replaces to not show the world his application code, with a slipup.  Been there. =)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your model should look like the following, you may disagree with me. But from my understanding a `User` can have many `Blogs` and a blog can belong to a user

```
  class Blogs < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user 
     attr_accessible :id, :name, :description
    end
```

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base

      attr_accessible :id, :email, :gender
      has_many :blogs
    end
```

Then I believe based on what you mentioned:

> I want to display all the user_blogs they belong to

You could do something like the following in your view:

```
 <% @users.each do |patient| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.custom_id %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <% user.blogs.each do |blog| %>
          <li><%= blog.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: yeah i just saw it was a typo